# R (Studio) Import xlsx/csv and set NA/missing on a per column basis

Tags: r, dataframe, import, na, missing-data

Probably a quick question that I just haven't found the right keywords to get an answer to.

I'm using R studio and importing a csv using `readr` (or an xlsx with `readxl`) of a large epidemiological data set (>40k rows, >200 variables) that was provided to me.

```
library (readr)
DF <- read_csv("com16_NA.csv", na = "999")
## OR ## 
library(readxl)
DF <- read_excel("com16_NA.xlsx", na = "999")
```

I'm trying to set the missing values on import, however the creators have set missing placeholders as 99 for some variables, 999 for others (where 99 is a valid option such e.g. weight) and again 9999 for others (where 999 is possible).

Is there a way on import to set the missing values on a per column basis? Right now I can only see how to set a single value as missing for the entire data set (as per the code above).

Or is my best bet to convert all of the missing placeholders to `NA` in a spreadsheet before importing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd let the creators know it's bad practice to have missing value codes that apply to some columns but not others!

You can use the `replace_with_na()` function from the `naniar` package in this case:

```
library(readr)
library(naniar)

DF <- read_csv("com16_NA.csv") %>%
  replace_with_na(replace = list(x = 99, y = 999))
```

where `x` is the column name with missing values set as `99` and `y` with `999`,

Comment: This looks like it will work - but will probably take me a some time to write code to process the entire data set due to the number of variables. Thanks! I'll be sure to report back on completion.

Comment: Solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both `read_csv` and `read_excel` accept a character vector for the `na` argument, so you can enter:

```
DF <- read_csv("com16_NA.csv", na = c('', 'NA', '999'))
```

Or include any other value you want to be `NA`. The default `na` argument is both `na = c('', 'NA')` for `read_csv` and just `''` for `read_excel`

Comment: Thanks for the insight - I'm sure it will be useful in the future. However, this doesn't solve the issue because the missing data notation is consistent within the column but not across columns. I.e. Column 1 thru 9 missing is "99". Column 10 missing is "999" because 99 is a valid response. Then column 20, missing is "9999" because 999 is a valid response. If I use this method e.g.: DF <- read_csv("com16_NA.csv", na = c('', 'NA',  '99', '999', '9999')) I would be omitting a lot of valid data.